# unable to recognize "deployment.yml": yaml: line 3: mapping values are not allowed in this context

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, gitlab-ci, kubectl, gitlab-ci-runner

I have setup a gitlab CI/CD pipeline, which builds and deploys docker images to kubernetes. I'm using yaml based deployment to kubernetes. When i run the pipeline the gitlab-runner always throws "**unable to recognize yaml line 3: mapping values are not allowed in this context**", but when i run it directly using kubectl create -f deployment.yaml, it runs correctly.

Here's my first few lines of the yml file. I have already validated the yml formatting. The error is thrown at line 3.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: configserver
  name: configserver
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8888
  selector:
    app: configserver

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: configserver
  name: configserver
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: configserver
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: configserver
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: config-server:latest
        name: configserver
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8888
        resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
```

It this something to do with gitlab?

Thanks.

**EDIT**:

Here's the relevant part of my .gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn clean install -DskipTests
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose-istio.yml build
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose-istio.yml push

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - kubectl apply -f itp-ms-deploy.yml
    - kubectl apply -f itp-ms-gateway.yml
    - kubectl apply -f itp-ms-autoscale.yml
  when: manual
  only:
    - master
```

Comment: can you show your gitlab ci definition?

Comment: i get the same error on gitlab ci many times, most of the time its a spare comma or dot somewhere in the yaml file, not in the first line. search for something like that or upload the whole document.

Comment: @EfratLevitan i have already validated the yml. it works when i run the command directly from CLI

Comment: @Thomas i have added the relevant part

Comment: what is the link between yaml of your `Service` and the `deployment.yml` you tried to apply ?

Comment: Do you have multiple objects concatenated in the `deployment.yaml` file?

Comment: @weibeld yes. i have updated the yml file.

Comment: If you do `kubectl apply -f deployment.yml` with exactly this YAML file, it works?

Comment: @weibeld yes. actually i noticed, that i get the yaml error for any kubectl commands i run from gitlab yml, like even kubectl get nodes

Comment: Only when you run kubectl commands from the GitLab YAML or any command? Are you sure the error isn't in the GitLab YAML?

Comment: Can you post the entire GitLab YAML?

Comment: @weibeld i have uploaded the entire gitlab-ci file. only the kubectl commands fail. could this be because gitlab-runner is not able to access kubernetes apis?